# Replace string value of iframe

Tags: php, str-replace

I have string that goes like this

```
$string = ' <iframe width="560px" height="250px" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBdVKAGo41VFI44444440l17aXhg&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

I need new string to replace data attributes to look like this

```
$newstring = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBdVKAGo41VFI44444440l17aXhg&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

I dont know value of data attbibutes but i know it will always be **100%**

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try php Preg_replace which is used to replace string part using regex

```
$string = preg_replace("/\"([0-9]*)px\"/si","'100%'",$string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works but longer than `preg_replace`:

```
$string = ' <iframe width="560px" height="250px"src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBdVKAGo41VFI44444440l17aXhg&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$pos = strpos($string, "src");
$newstring = substr_replace($string,' <iframe width="100%" height="100%" ',0,$pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_replace()` you can do it like this

```
$string = ' <iframe width="560px" height="250px" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBdVKAGo41VFI44444440l17aXhg&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

$s = preg_replace('/(width|height)="[0-9]*px"/', '$1="100%"', $string);
echo $s;
```

Using the `(width|height)` makes sure you only change those 2 attributes.

Result:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyBdVKAGo41VFI44444440l17aXhg&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the height and width of an html element you simply include a good old css file in your html document or php template file.No need for regexps or dom parsing.

Since your iframe looks like you get it from google and it doesn't have a class or id you put it inside a div or whatever that has an id in case you have other iframes in the page.

```
div#maps-iframe-container iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```